# Can I install the Krita Thumbnails for Nautilus by using apt-get command?

Tags: apt, nautilus, nautilus-extensions, krita

I want to install the Krita Thumbnails for Nautilus by using `apt-get` command. Is it possible?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Install the package, then restart the system :

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS+ , Linux Mint 17.1/17.2/17.3+ , Elementary OS 0.3 Freya+:

[gnome-kra-ora_1-1_amd64.deb](http://www.davidrevoy.com/XYZ/gnome-kra-ora_1-1_amd64.deb)

Originally from project [gnome-kra-ora-thumbnailer](https://github.com/Deevad/gnome-kra-ora-thumbnailer)

SRC: [Krita thumbnails for Nautilus,Nemo file browser - David Revoy](http://www.davidrevoy.com/article194/krita-thumbnails-for-nautilus-nemo-file-browser)

Answer (score 1):

First, nowdays you should use `apt` instead of `apt-get` for such simple tasks. Use `apt search krita` to see all packages related to krita. I do not see thumbnails there, so it seems you will need to find the appropriate PPA or download a package somewhere.